# Symfony 2 delete app.php from link

Tags: php, symfony, routes, localhost

I used symfony 2 and already have created my application. I renamed my `app.php` to `trainingboard.php`. Now localhost route for index action now is: `http://localhost/trainingboard/web/trainingboard.php/`. How can I delete `trainingboard.php` from my link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `web/.htaccess` file change:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ trainingboard.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: After that I crossed to `http://localhost/trainingboard/web/` but I had to chose `trainingboard.php`. I want to delete it from link, so my index page will be `http://localhost/trainingboard/web/` or `http://localhost/trainingboard/` for example.

Comment: Take a look at your Apache Virtual Host configuration. If there is a  DirectoryIndex set, change it from app.php to trainingboard.php